# How to send data from the 5th activity to the 1st activity?

Tags: java, android

I am using 5 activities. from activity1 I move to activity2, from act2 to act3, from act3 to act4 and from act4 to act5.
activity 2 carries data to act3 and like this act5 receives data of act2, act3, act4 and then send all data to act 1.

My First activity

```
I{

    Intent i= new Intent(firstactivity.this, secondactivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, 10);

  }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 10) {

        String a= data.getStringExtra("Value1");
        String b= data.getStringExtra("Value2");
        String c= data.getStringExtra("Value3");
        String d= data.getStringExtra("Value4");

        String showall = a+", "+b+", "+c+", "+d;
        address.setText(showall);

    }
```

My Second activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(secondactivity.this, thirdactivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
            intent.putExtra("Value1", firstvalue);
            startActivity(intent);
```

My Fifth activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(fourthactivity.this, fifthactivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Value1", geta);
            intent.putExtra("Value2", getb);
            intent.putExtra("Value3", getc);
            intent.putExtra("Value4", getd);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
            setResult(10);

            finish();
```

Comment: You'd better use a single Activity and have some Fragments to swap inside it. The data would belong to the Activity, and all the Fragments could handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(fifthactivity.this, firstactivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Value1", geta);
intent.putExtra("Value2", getb);
intent.putExtra("Value3", getc);
intent.putExtra("Value4", getd);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

And then process your passed result in `onCreate` (in case activity got destroyed) or `onNewIntent` (if your activity is still running but you bring it to front and update it with new intent) of your `firstactivity`

Answer (score 0):

```
 //A simple approach to solve this issue is to use sharedpreferences 

//store value from activity five
getsharedpreferences('temp','MODE_PRIVATE').edit().clear().putString('values','new value').apply();

//get values from shared preferences if its available
String value 5 = getsharedpreferences('temp','MODE_PRIVATE').getString('values','nil');
getsharedpreferences('temp','MODE_PRIVATE').edit().clear();
```

Comment: it is better to use shared preferences than sending back-forth.Hope issues gets fixed

Answer (score 0):

first activity

```
static ArrayList<String> arlist=new ArrayList<String>();
arlist.add("value");
arlist.add("value1");
arlist.add("value2");
```

In second Activity

```
ActivityOne.arlist
```

Comment: Plz advice how can I do this.

Comment: check update. Do this if your list is not so secured.